# Stop scrolling header image on Big Cartel website

Tags: css, bigcartel

I am currently working on customising my Big Cartel website and I've ran into the issue of the header image that scrolls with the page when using the Parade theme.

This is okay for my main shop page but for my Lookbook page, it is covering my content too much and I wish for it to either be hidden or stop scrolling.

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Thank you so much!

```
.header {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 97;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .header {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}
.header.overlay-header {
  position: relative;
}
.header .primary-header {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.header .secondary-header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.header .header-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! please, edit your post and put your code so I can help. About how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello @CharlesJensen. Please provide some code with your question so it is easier for us to understand your problem :)

Comment: Hi Karl! I apologise, but I'm very new to this so I'm not exactly sure if the issue we're looking for is in this code but this is what I could find of the code that relates to the "header".

Answer (score 0):

Your header is `fixed` so it'll be in a fixed position relative to the viewport. Just make it `relative` or remove the position all together to make it `static`.

```
.header {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 97;
}
```

It'd be very beneficial to you to understand the `position` property going forward, so here's a small overview.

There are **5 different position values** you need to know;

**Static (default)**

> An element with `position: static;` is not positioned in any special
>   way; it is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page. This is the definition of `position` if you don't explicitly set one in your CSS.

**Relative**

> An element with `position: relative;` is positioned relative to its
>   normal position where it falls in the hierarchy.
>
> Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a
>   relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from
>   its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into
>   any gap left by the element.

**Fixed**

> An element with `position: fixed;` is positioned relative to the
>   viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the
>   page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used
>   to position the element. If you set a navbar to `fixed` at the top, it'll always be at the top of the view. If you set a footer to `fixed` at the bottom, it'll always be at the bottom of the view and remain there when scrolling.

**Absolute**

> An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the
>   nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the
>   viewport, like fixed).
>
> However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned
>   ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page
>   scrolling.
>
> Personally I recommend being a bit cautious with `absolute`
>   positioning and really only use it for overlays and layering as an
>   element positioned `absolute` will ignore the flow of the document.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @CharlesJensen in my edit I added a small overview from W3Schools for you.